# I bought an Android ringtone at Google Play Store on my PC. How do I transfer it to my phone and select it as my ringtone?

Tags: hardware, google, ringtone

I bought an Android ringtone at Google Play Store on my PC. How do I transfer it to my phone and select it as my ringtone? The song is Money Talks by ACDC. I bought it at this link: [Google Play link to buy ringtone](https://play.google.com/store/music/album?id=Bgmlvigu7en2xlv2xu74bcp556m&tid=song-Twbvy5rstsayepvwtby7lasqxrq&hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

Follow this -

```
Menu > Settings > Sound > Phone ringtone > Sound picker > Music library > Select tone
```

Remember, this is the general way to pick a tone in Xperia (Sony) phones. Terminology may be different in other devices.

Comment: The ring tone does not appear as a ringtone option under settings with the other ring tones. It only plays in Google Play Music app. It was sold to me by Google Play as a ring tone and yet this happens.

Comment: Download any other music player and search the tone. Tap and hold on it to see various options like Use as, Set as, etc.